# How to convert .aiff to .caf through converter or programmatically?

Tags: ios, audio

Any one knows how I can convert my .aiff audio file to .caf audio file?
Any Converter any link will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to convert audio files programmatically, or are looking for some app/software ??

Comment: I am asking through some Application not programmatically.

Comment: will terminal script work for you?

Comment: Yes, Thanks every tech will work please suggest.

Comment: This is definitely not a question for StackOverflow and should be moved to SuperUser. StackOverflow is strictly a programming Q&A website, and you're strictly asking for not a programatic solution.

Comment: Just learned that posts more than 60 days old can't be migrated. Okay, then in that case, this needs to be closed entirely for being off-topic. If you'd like to reopen it, go to SuperUser and post it as a new question.

Comment: You specifically asked for a non-programmatic answer (on a programming forum) and then accepted a programmatic answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how to do it in terminal:

`afconvert -f caff -d aacl@22050 -c 1 sound.aiff sound.caf`

All files in directory script:

```
for f in *; do
if [ "$f" != "converttocaf.sh" ]
then
/usr/bin/afconvert -f caff -d 'aac ' -c 1 -l Mono $f
echo "$f converted"
fi
done
```

Comment: Where it will store the changed file?

Comment: in the same directory, just go to your directory `cd ~/Sounds` and do afconvert

Comment: It converts and creates the new file but the created file does not sound as caf works on ipod/iphone etc.

Comment: it is just compressed differently, you can try with other parameters and formats. `afconvert --help-formats` is the list of all formats, just look for caf data formats and you can use them instead of `aacl`. You can choose another rate as well instead of 22050, just type `afconvert -h` and look at `General options`. And it is always a balance between quality and size...

Answer (score 1):

I have directly converted a wav file in caf file by using this command:

afconvert -f caff -d LEI16 -c 1 trampoline.wav trampoline.caf

you can also find some useful commands about the best practices to convert the file extentions on the fillowing link:
http://gamua.com/blog/2010/06/sound-on-ios-best-practices/

Comment: this link has much better explanation than i gave you, thanks for it